# union of different types using linq2db

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core, linq2db

I have type definition of DocumentField_1 & DocumentField_2, which is totally different.

DocumentField_1 has records if assigned value is true otherwise record will not be there, so it is of boolean type. and DocumentField_2 has value with date.

I have following query in sql which I want to write using linq2db.

What is the way to do that having said that those are of different types (boolean & date)?

```
select 'True' from DocumentField_1 where DocumentField_1.DocumentId = 2
union all
select CONVERT(varchar, value) from DocumentField_2 where DocumentField_2.DocumentId = 2
```

schema of DocumentField_1 is

```
Id          -> int
DocumentId  -> int
```

schema of DocumentField_2 is

```
Id          -> int
DocumentId  -> int
Value       -> datetime
```

Comment: I wonder what is your dbms that doesn't throw on `select .., (select .. union select  ..) as value ..` every time when inner selects return distinct values?

Comment: i have updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be simple:

```cs
subquery1.Select(_ => “True”).UnionAll(subquery2.Select(_ => _.Date.ToString());
```

Instead of `ToString()`, you can also use `Sql.Convert` / `Sql.Convert2` extensions to customize format